# Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: No such user here

Tags: c#, iis-7

I am using the below code in web.config and the email is sent to my gmail account without any problem. But when i am trying to send the same email to mycompany email, I get the error " System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: No such user here". But i very much have the mailbox . Is there something i am missing?? Please advice me!! Thank you very much in advance!!

This is in new IIS 7.5 using ASP.net application.

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
            <network host="localhost" port="25" defaultCredentials="true" clientDomain="" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

In asp.net

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Send(message);
```

Comment: The error isn't coming from your code, it's coming from the mail server.  Have you double-checked the account that you're sending to and made sure it's correct?  You might also use something like Fiddler or WireShark to monitor the actual SMTP call and see if there's any useful information in there.  Beyond that, your next step would be to check with the mail server administrator to find out why the server is bouncing the message back.

Comment: @David, I have setup SMTp and i am not sure what i messed up. I will try to use Fiddler and see if i get an idea what's wrong!! I created a remote SMTP and when i use that SMTP host, i get the same error for all the EMail ID's i specify but when i use localhost it works for Gmail and not for company email ID.

Comment: What email address are you attempting to send email to?  Does that email account exist on the target SMTP server?

Comment: @Amy, i am afraid i don't know!! Can you please tell me little more clearly about having email account on target server or suggest me a link?

Comment: **What email address are you attempting to send email to?**

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this exception with two Change:
 1. change smtp port from '25' to '587'
 2. change credential user name from '*Admin*' to '*Admin@leilakarimi.ir*'

I hope your problem fix with this changes

Comment: you can call your E-mail server support group and ask for help, they will correct your code.

Comment: Port 587: 
This is the default mail submission port. When a mail client or server is submitting an email to be routed by a proper mail server, it should always use this port.

All Mailgun customers should consider using this port as default, unless you're explicitly blocked by your upstream network or hosting provider. This port, coupled with TLS encryption, will ensure that email is submitted securely and following the guidelines set out by the IETF.
http://blog.mailgun.com/25-465-587-what-port-should-i-use/

Answer (score 2):

Recently my hosting provider changed the policies for the mailbox passwords, I was using an account created just to send automated emails so I never changed the password.

I started getting  this error until I updated the credentials of the account. Not very descriptive error for my situation.

Comment: This is more suited for a comment than an answer

Comment: @leonheess, I know, but I do not have enough reputation to write comments. My options was to create an answer or just do nothing. Thanks

Comment: I upvoted your answer, so you hopefully have enough reputation until next time (: